# Is Obama the first American president to ever visit Hiroshima?

Tags: united-states, president, history, nuclear-weapons, world-war-ii

In most articles about Obama's visit to Hiroshima, they say that [the visit is the first to Hiroshima by a sitting U.S. president](http://wapo.st/1WZhg8c).

This implies that there may have been visits by presidents before or after their tenure in office. Have non-sitting  presidents ever visited Hiroshima? If so, which ones?

Comment: Not really an answer, but Nixon visited before becoming president. From the Atlantic: [*"and Richard Nixon went on April 11, 1964, four years before he won the presidential election"*](https://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2016/05/hiroshima-us-presidents-visit/482067/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jimmy Carter has visited Hiroshima. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_visitors_to_the_Hiroshima_Peace_Memorial_Museum

[This Forbes article](http://fortune.com/2016/05/27/obama-first-president-hiroshima/) mentions Carter but no-one else, suggesting he's the only one.